# What happened to the x's in the denominator?

Tags: inequality, factoring

$$\frac{x+2}{4x\:}=\frac{3x-1}{3x}$$

Putting this code into Cymath, the first step is: "*Cancel x on both sides.*" Then "*Multiply both sides by 12 (the LCM of 4, 3)*."

How was that possible? What method or teaching did they use to be able to do it and how was it done?

I tried the equation in Symbol and Quickmath and both have steps that do:

$$3x(x + 2) = 4x(3x - 1)$$

Wouldn't I do $3x * x = 3x^2$? The solutions show, it is just $3x$. So what happened to the $x$?

Comment: Multiplying by $x$ cancels with the $x$ on the denominator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to multiply both sides by $3x$ and $4x$ as Symbol and Quickmath do. It's enough to multiply both sides by $3, 4$ and $x$, and simplify the resulting fractions. That way, you get
$$
3(x+2)=4(3x-1)
$$
Cymath seems to treat "multiply both sides by $x$" and "multiply both sides by $12$" as two completely different kinds of operations, which, to be fair, is probably necessary in a computer program. We humans, however, can treat the two as basically the same.

Just remember that multiplying by something with $x$ *might* introduce extra solutions into our equation. For instance, Symbol's and Quickmath's multiplication by $3x\cdot 4x=12x^2$ gives us an equation where $x=0$ is a solution, even though that's not a solution to the original equation.

**PS:** Note that *strictly speaking*, using the formal, rigorous, conventional definition of fractions, the expression
$$
\frac{x+2}{4x}=\frac{3x-1}{3x}
$$
truly means
$$
3x(x+2)=4x(3x-1)
$$
(as long as the denominators aren't $0$). So calling that step of going from the top one to the bottom one "multiply on both sides" is imprecise. The step is actually called "apply the definition of fractions".